# How to add an isOnline flag with $lookup operator in MongoDb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, nosql, backend

I am working on a messaging application, where I need to show whether a chat participant is online or offline. So I am using a $lookup operator in an aggregation to populate chat participants, while reading their login session information accordingly. But I have not been able to properly populate the **`isOnline`** flag for each chat participant.

So I have a **`User`** schema that looks like below:

```
User {
   _id: ObjectId("123456789xx")
   first_name: "Sam",
   last_name: "Jones",
   email: "samjones@gmail.com",
   inbox: [
      {
          participant: ObjectId("1XXXXXXXXX"),
          added_at: "12:00:00 09/21/2021"
      },
      {
          participant: ObjectId("2XXXXXXXXX"),
          added_at: "12:00:00 11/21/2022"
      },
   ]
}
```

I also have a **`session`** schema that looks like:

```
Session {
  _id: "XXXuid",
  expire: "12:00:00 07/01/2023",
  session: {
     userId: "1XXXXXXXXX",
     name: "Sam Smith",
     email: "samsmith@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

if a user is currently logged in, he/she will show up in the **`Session`** table/collection.

Now I need to populate the **`participants`** in the user's inbox field using **`$lookup`** operator. This is what my **`$lookup`** looks like in aggregation:

```
{
  $lookup: {
     from:"Users",
     localField:"inbox.participant",
     foreignField: "_id",
     as: "participants",
     pipeline:[
       {
          $addField: {
              isOnline: false
          }
       }
     ]
  }
}
```

Question: how can I populate the isOnline status for each one of the participant so I can have something like:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("123456789xx")
   first_name: "Sam",
   last_name: "Jones",
   email: "samjones@gmail.com",
   inbox: [
      {
          participant: {
             first_name:"Sam",
             last_name: "Smith",
             email: "samsmith@gmail.com",
             isOnline: true 
          },
          added_at: "12:00:00 09/21/2021"
      },
      {
          participant: {
             first_name:"Emily",
             last_name: "Grande",
             email: "emilygrande@gmail.com",
             isOnline: false
          },
          added_at: "12:00:00 11/21/2022"
      },
   ]
}
```

Comment: I think you'll want to `$unwind` on `inbox` and then do a `$lookup` and then do a `$addField`

Comment: This question is very similar to your previous question.  You could adapt the previous answer to solve this issue also.